# Declare a variable outside a method and access it from the method in groovy

Tags: groovy, jmeter

Want to declare a variable `count` outside a method and access it from the method in groovy.

```
def count = 0;
void PostMeasurement() {
  def httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(new BasicHttpParams());
  def httpPost = new HttpPost();
  httpPost.setURI(new URI(vars.get("InfluxDBAPI")));
  count = count + 1;
        if(count == 10) {
            httpPost.setEntity(new StringEntity(Metrics));
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpPost);
            EntityUtils.consumeQuietly(response.getEntity());
        
        }
        else {}  .
}
```

Error I am getting:

```
No such property: count for class: Script482
    at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.eval(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:320) ~[groovy-jsr223-3.0.11.jar:3.0.11]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyCompiledScript.eval(GroovyCompiledScript.java:71) ~[groovy-jsr223-3.0.11.jar:3.0.11]
    at javax.script.CompiledScript.eval(CompiledScript.java:93) ~[java.scripting:?]
    at org.apache.jmeter.util.JSR223TestElement.processFileOrScript(JSR223TestElement.java:217) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.5]
    at org.apache.jmeter.visualizers.JSR223Listener.sampleOccurred(JSR223Listener.java:54) ~[ApacheJMeter_components.jar:5.5]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.ListenerNotifier.notifyListeners(ListenerNotifier.java:58) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.5]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.notifyListeners(JMeterThread.java:1037) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.5]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.doEndTransactionSampler(JMeterThread.java:673) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.5]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:478) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.5]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:268) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.5]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[?:?]
Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: count for class: Script482
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:65) ~[groovy-3.0.11.jar:3.0.11]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoGetPropertySite.getProperty(PogoGetPropertySite.java:51) ~[groovy-3.0.11.jar:3.0.11]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callGroovyObjectGetProperty(AbstractCallSite.java:341) ~[groovy-3.0.11.jar:3.0.11]
    at Script482.PostMeasurement(Script482.groovy:4) ~[?:?]
    at Script482.run(Script482.groovy:17) ~[?:?]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.eval(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:317) ~[groovy-jsr223-3.0.11.jar:3.0.11]
    ... 10 more
```

How to achieve this ?

Comment: The code looks good and it should work. What problem do you have with current declaration of the variable?

Comment: Have updated the error

Comment: I think it's something related to the way you run the script and how it generates the executable class (`Script482`)

Answer (score 3):

Coming from Java, it's a bit tricky: Groovy makes you think you're at the top level of the script, when in fact you're trapped in the `main()` method (well known from Java) of the script class.
If you declare a variable within the `main()` method in Java, you cannot access it from other methods.
There are two ways to break out of the main method.

1. Create a class variable with the `@Field` annotation

```
@groovy.transform.Field count = 0

PostMeasurement()

assert count == 1

void PostMeasurement() {
    count = count + 1
}
```

2. Use the script's binding to store the variable. For that, just omit the keyword `def`.

```
count = 0

PostMeasurement()

assert count == 1
assert getBinding().variables.count == 1

void PostMeasurement() {
    count = count + 1
}
```